# How to disable to git delta compression when garbage collecting

Tags: git

I'm trying to run `git gc` on a repo but it fails because it run out of memory at the delta compression phase. I assume it's because some object are too big. Is there a way to avoid this memory problem (or disable the compression) ?

Comment: Does `git gc --aggressive` change anything? And after `git config core.deltaBaseCacheLimit 96m`? (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/24978239/6309)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test the settings of "[Stopping a `git gc --aggressive`, is that a bad thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6066772/6309)"

```
git config pack.threads 1
git config pack.deltaCacheSize 1
git config core.packedGitWindowSize 16m
git config core.packedGitLimit 128m
git config pack.windowMemory 512m
```

Followed by:

```
git gc --aggressive
```

Check also, if you have a Git2.0+ (so not a git for Windows, limited to 1.9.5), [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22914119/6309):

```
git gc --aggressive --depth=x
```

(try different values from the default 250 one)

Update May 2017: Git 2.13.x/2.14 (Q3 2017) will increase `core.packedGitLimit` considerable (up to 32 GiB!).
See "[fatal: early EOF fatal: `index-pack` failed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44010983/6309)".

Comment: I'm stuck with git 1.7.2.5. Anyway, the first solution took forevere but worked ! Thx